# Is it possible to save a variable in a file between executions?

Tags: python

I'm trying to be able to save a list of lists in my program so that if it is updated the next time I run the code it will remain updated.
I know this is possible by writing it to an external text program however I would prefer a solution where I am able to keep it within the single python file.

Comment: Script files are not for storing data. Databases, JSON files, CSV files, TXT files, pickle files and a lot of other options that are not script files are meant for storing data. Why do you have the need to store it in a single python file?

Comment: Variables of any type within python don’t save between runs. Writing to a text file is your best shot.

Comment: You can't. You need to save the data somewhere else and read it back in upon the next execution. When a python file is executed, it is loaded into memory and when the execution finishes, anything that is created or modified in memory will be destroyed, unless you actively save it elsewhere.

Comment: Why would you prefer that? It's a bad idea, and as others have indicated you have several other options, including saving it to a text file like you suggest yourself. What would be better about modifying a source file, with all the problems and risks that brings with it?

Comment: Surely it is possible - it's just a really bad idea. But in the spirit of learning you can try it out yourself and figure out all the havoc it will create. Simply open the current python script file with `with open('C:/path_to_file/pyfile.py', 'a') as fo: fo.write('some string')` - this will append `some string` to the end of your script file every time you run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In continuation of my comment, I have made a small script that updates itself each time you run the code.

The variable `last_run` is updated to reflect the random numbers generated in the prior run.

```
import numpy as np

last_run = [7, 3, 6, 0, 2]
print(f'last run was: {last_run}')

with open(__file__, 'r') as fo:
    lines = fo.readlines()
lines[2] = f"{lines[2][:11]}{list(np.random.randint(0, 10, 5))}\n"

with open(__file__, 'w') as fo:
    fo.writelines(lines)
```

I have to mention that a lot of issues can arise with such a setup, and it would in all cases be much preferred to simply store your variable in a data file - a text file might do for your setup. A solution with a text file could look something like this

```
import numpy as np
import os

text_file_path = __file__ + r'/../text_file.txt'

if os.path.isfile(text_file_path):
    with open(text_file_path, 'r') as fo:
        last_run = fo.readlines()[0]
else:
    last_run = []

print(f'last run was: {last_run}')

with open(text_file_path, 'w') as fo:
    fo.write(str(np.random.randint(0, 10, 5)))
```